# Forcing an application's window to open in the workspace in which it was run

Tags: linux, window-manager, awesome-wm

It takes a second or two to open a program (i.e. - Anki or Slack), and I often open multiple programs at a time—in different workspaces. Here's what I would like to happen:

- Press `Mod + R` and type in "anki" in `Workspace 1`
- Switch to `Workspace 2` press `Mod + R` and type in "discord"
- Switch to `Workspace 3` press `Mod + R` and type in "libreoffice"
- Switch to `Workspace 4` and browse Firefox
- Anki opens in `Workspace 1`, Discord opens in `Workspace 2`, Libre Office opens in `Workspace 3`, all while I'm viewing `Workspace 4`.

Instead, what ends up happening is that Anki, Discord, and Libre Office all open in `Workspace 4`, regardless of which workspace I was viewing when I ran them.

Is there a way of achieving the above bulleted situation ***without* having to explicitly assign a program to a workspace**? (I might not always want Anki in `Workspace 1`, for example; I want it to open in w/e workspace I was viewing when I typed "anki".)

Answer (score 0):

I've made your question my task for tonight and I managed to get a working version. Be careful it is rather hacky! As far as I know there's no other way to do that. Especially because there's a [bug](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/1482) in awesome with applying rules.

What we are doing? When executing `Mod4 + r` we save the current focused tag to a list. When applying rules to appearing windows we pop the corresponding tag from the list. We need the once function because awesome has a bug at the moment and applies rules twice to a window. We have to exclude our terminal emulator (and all other programs we start with key binding) from that because otherwise it's being opened on the tag where we last pressed `Mod4 + r`.

You need the following functions in your rc.lua.

```
local rule_count = 0
local tag_count = 0
local run_tag = {}

local function once()
  if rule_count == 1 then
    rule_count = 0
  else
    rule_count = 1
  end
  return rule_count
end

local function get_run_tag()
  if once() == 1 then
    if tag_count > 0 then
      tag_count = tag_count - 1
      return table.remove(run_tag)
    else
      return "1"
    end
  end
end

local function push_run_tag(tag)
  table.insert(run_tag, tag)
  tag_count = tag_count + 1
end
```

Then look for the following part in your rc.lua:

```
{ rule_any = {type = { "normal", "dialog" }},
    properties = { titlebars_enabled = false } -- or true
},
```

And add some lines so it looks like that:

```
{ rule_any = {type = { "normal", "dialog" }},
    except_any = { class = { "Termite" }},
    properties = { titlebars_enabled = false, tag = function() return 
get_run_tag() end}
},
```

You have to replace `Termite` with the console emulator which you usually start with `Mod4 + return`. In addition to that you need to add each program to the class table you want to start with key bindings.

Then look for the `Mod4 + r` key binding. At the moment it should like this one:

```
awful.key({ modkey }, "r", awful.screen.focused().mypromptbox:run()
          {description = "run prompt", group = "launcher"}),
```

Change it so it look like this:

```
awful.key({ modkey }, "r", function ()
  awful.screen.focused().mypromptbox:run()
  push_run_tag(awful.screen.focused().selected_tag.name)
end,
          {description = "run prompt", group = "launcher"}),
```

I would appreciate better solutions!

PS: This won't work for applications like Steam because it pops up multiple windows. The first one gets the correct tag. The following are spawning on tag "1".